# Detecting KeyEvents for keys that require Shift to be pressed

Tags: java, keyevent, keycode, key-events

I have a question about `(scene).setOnKeyPressed()`. I am trying to make a simple calculator, but something weird happens with the key-codes.

This is a small portion of my code:

```
switch (KeyEvent.getCode()) {
    case PLUS:
      plus.fire();
      break;
    case MINUS:
      min.fire();
      break;
    case EQUALS:
      // something
}
```

So everything is fine with the <kbd>−</kbd>, but because you need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get to the <kbd>+</kbd> key (at least on my keyboard) it doesn't go to the <kbd>+</kbd>-case, rather it goes to the <kbd>=</kbd>-case (which is *beneath* the <kbd>+</kbd> on my keyboard).

Is there any way for me to detect a key pressed of a key which needs <kbd>Shift</kbd>-pressed first?

Comment: thanks for whoever made the question better looking :)

Answer (score 1):

For any key pressed with valid key output (like +, -, =), 3 keyevents are generated (KEY_PRESSED,KEY_TYPED,KEY_RELEASED). 
Make sure **only** KEY_TYPED events are getting called for processing inside switch case.

```
    if(keyEvent.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED) { // this will only process KEY_TYPED event
    switch (KeyEvent.getCode()) {
        case PLUS:
          plus.fire();
          break;
        case MINUS:
          min.fire();
          break;
        case EQUALS:
          // something
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my own answer to the problem:

It works, but is it any good? Is there perhaps a better solution?

```
    case EQUALS:
      if(KeyEvent.isShiftDown())
        plus.fire();
        break;
      else
        equals.fire();
        break;
      break;
```